# JavaFX TabPane: How to make trapezoid Tab

Tags: css, javafx, tabs

I want to make `TabPane` look like this below image

[image]

But I can't figure out how to achieve this. I only can make like this image

[image]

This is the `css` style I use for styling `TabPane`

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-width: 90px;
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-shape: "M300,290 L310,168 L410,168 L421,290 L300,290 z";
}

.tab {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: white;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.tab .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the only problem you have is that the tab headers don't overlap in your version, yes?

Comment: yes I want the tab header overlap, but also if possible I want the horizontal line styled with TabPane without make it manually